# How to use between date query?

Tags: 8, database

I have 2 fields in a node and I'm trying to get the expired nodes set in "Start Date" and "End Date" field.

I'm using db_select to get the start and end date values.

How can I add a condition to check if the dates are in range?

Here's my current code:-

```
$query = db_select('node__field_end_date', 'ed');

$query->leftJoin('node__field_start_date', 'sd', 'sd.entity_id = ed.entity_id');

// Date values showing as a formatted date
$query->addField('ed', 'node__field_end_date', 'date_end');
$query->addField('sd', 'field_start_date_value', 'date_start');
```

Answer (score 1):

The raw SQL would be something like this,

```
SELECT startDate, endDate
FROM YourTable
WHERE GETDATE() between startDate and endDate;
```

You might could do like this with db_select

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition(now(), array(node__field_start_date, node__field_end_date), 'BETWEEN');
```

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your response. however, I would like to know how to do it using db_select

Comment: I have updated the answer now

Comment: @CatherineSalvador Did my anser help you, if yes then please give it the chekmark so that future visitors can find the right answer easily.

Comment: sorry for late response. I haven't tried it yet as I have switched to another project. I'll check on that now. thanks

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
db_select
  ...
  ->condition('date_field_1', $min_date, '>');
  ->condition('date_field_2', $max_date, '<=')
```